# How do I delete a spreadsheet that I have created from testing?

Tags: spring-boot, google-sheets-api

I have the most recent version of the Java Google Api client. I am successfully able to Authenticate and create a Spreadsheet.

How can I delete the spreadsheets that I have created after each JUNIT test.

I would like to be able to use the api to delete the Spreadsheet

Comment: When you want to delete files in Google Drive using API, you can use the delete method of Drive API. You can see the information at [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete). If this was not useful information for your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: So do I need to update the scope to use the api? Also, is the spreadsheet id the name of the file?

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot here to tell if you'll need multiple scopes. If you plan on doing any spreadsheet actions using the same flow, then yes. 
Drive actions use `DriveScopes.DRIVE.`
But if all you want to do is read the list of files you only need the Drive scope.
So:

```java
final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

// parse through the retrieved list of files to find a match with the name you gave the
// sheet. Since you can create multiple sheets with the same name, I parse the entire
// and delete all the files with that name. 

FileList result = service
    .files()
    .list()
    .setPageSize(100)
    .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
    .execute();

List<File> files = result.getFiles();

for (File file : files) {
    if (file.getName().trim().compareTo(getTitle().trim()) == 0) {
        Delete d = fileService.files().delete(file.getId());
        d.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot one point which is very important in the consideration of whether you want multiple Scopes. If you are just testing in eclipse or something, you can simply use the Scope you want in the Class. But if you are exporting an application, you will want to make sure your first request is with the full range of scopes you want to use. That's because your app will store a token with those scopes, and that token will be used through the application. Much thanks to the editor who made my response easier to read.